# Последовательность

Tags: pascal

Добрый день. Уже целый день ломаю голову как оптимизированно написать сумму последовательности 1 - 1/2 + 1/3-....+1/9999 - 1/10000.

Comment: Оптимизированно относительно чего и по какому параметру?

Comment: Оптимизированно - это `ln(2)`

Comment: `=(1-1/2) + (1/3-1/4) + (1/5-1/6) + ... + (1/9999-1/10000)=1/(1*2) + 1/(3*4) + 1/(5*6) + ... + 1/(9999*10000)` Ну и считать "от хвоста" - это понизит ошибку вычисления.

Answer (score -1):

```
result := 0;
for i := 1 to n do
result := result + (-1)*exp((i - 1)*ln(abs(-1)));
```

Как-то так, если правильно паскаль помню. Здесь n - ваше число членов и в обычном цикле все это считаем

Comment: Натуральный логарифм из -1? Это же `iπ`!

Comment: Натуральный логарифм из 1? Это же `0`!

Comment: Вы имели в виду `a^b = e^(b*ln(a))`, всё вроде верно было. Для положительных a)